# how to add site path in xammp localhost

Tags: php, css, xampp

i have a source code of a CMS the cms back-end working perfectly but in front-end shows errors the css not working properly i was searching for the solution then find

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <link href="<?php echo $sitepath; ?>/Assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
    <link href="<?php echo $sitepath; ?>/Assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="<?php echo $sitepath; ?>/Assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
    <link href="<?php echo $sitepath; ?>/Assets/css/sitestyles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
```

has not fixed

and am try to fix in include.php file here is the include file

```
$sitepath="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
//Replace with your domain name if you wish
//$sitepath="http://www.example.com";
```

this code working on my server but while use this code on my localhost xampp to change

```
$sitepath="http://localhost/cms".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
//Replace with your domain name if you wish
//$sitepath="http://www.example.com";
```

still shows the top code css not working the url shows

> localhost/cms/localhost/index.php

like this what i do help please

Comment: Why not setup a virtual host?

Comment: $sitepath="http ://localhost/cms/"; should be work ... btw don't use code without to try to understand what you do [leave the blank after http]

Comment: What is your `phpinfo()` value in Apache Configuration for `HTTP_HOST`, mine is "localhost" (and it looks like you have the same thing). What is the desired path?